# Vagrant Best Practice - Persistance

Tags: vagrant

I like how through vagrant I can spin up my machine, configure it and get to coding.  However when I do vagrant halt, and then do a vagrant up again, it rebuilds my machine from the base box.  All the new stuff I installed, my project repository is gone.

I can see that the virtual machine still exists in virtual box and I can use it from there, but I want to use vagrant to manage it and access it while keep the persistence of the disk as I would accessing it directly from virtual box.  My host is windows, my guest is precise64.

Thoughts?

Stephen

Comment: I wonder why `vagrant halt` destroys your virtual disk since it's supposed to work like a poweroff of the virtual maschine?

Comment: It's not that the halt destroys the VM.  The VM is still there in Virtual box, but I would expect that after I did halt, that vagrant up would spin up the same VM that has all my stuff in it as oppose to a completely new box.  I'm a wrong on this?

Comment: Is there something I need to do the the Vagrant file after initial creation of the VM to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use `vagrant suspend`? ([via](http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/getting-started/teardown.html))

Comment: suspend works fine, but I would suspect halt should do the same thing in that it would still use the same VM when i bring it back up.

Comment: I've come to terms that it's version 1.2.2.  I went back to 1.1.5 and all is well